# Sorting an object by value w/ `sort` and `reduce`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given an object with unsorted numeric values, such as:

```
const unsorted = {
  green: 80,
  blue: 90,
  red: 30,
  yellow: 100,
}
```

We want a data structure with the same key/value pairs sorted in descending order of the values, e.g.:

```
const sorted = {
  yellow: 100,
  blue: 90,
  green: 80,
  red: 30,
}
```

My solution:

```
function sortObjectByValue (obj) {
  const sorted = Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => obj[b] - obj[a])
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur] = obj[cur]
      return acc
    }, {})

  return new Map(Object.entries(sorted))
}
```

What I hope could be improved:

- Two iterations, first `sort` then `reduce`; this seems inefficient.
- Using `Map`. I wish we could just use objects, it would make using this elsewhere much easier. I doubt this can be avoided though, as we need to ensure that the order is preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my proposal:

```
function sortObjectByValue (obj) {
  const map = new Map()

  Object.entries(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => obj[b][1] - obj[a][1])
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      map.set(key, value)
    });

  return map;
}
```

You don't need to create a sorted object unless you want to use it, I understand that you are using a Map so that you can preserve the order of the elements, but keep in mind this:

> Note: Since ECMAScript 2015, objects do preserve creation order for
> string and Symbol keys. In JavaScript engines that comply with the
> ECMAScript 2015 spec, iterating over an object with only string keys
> will yield the keys in order of insertion.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

So with that in mind we can skip the Map and we have something like this:

```
function sortObjectByValue2 (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => obj[b] - obj[a])
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur] = obj[cur]
      return acc
    }, {})
}
```

Comment: Great that we can skip the `Map`! Thanks for pointing that out. Otherwise you think that a two-step `sort` + `reduce` is the most efficient way?

Comment: Yeah, 1 pass to convert object to array, 1 pass to sort, 1 pass to convert back to object. You may also be able to use the `Object.fromEntries` to do the conversion of sorted key-value pairs array to object, i.e. `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).sort(/* sort function */))`, but it's still the same number of passes over the data.

Comment: OK, that's what I was afraid of. Well at least we got rid of the `Map` (disclaimer: nothing against `Map`, just unneeded here).